# In Linux kernel, why not record TIF_NEED_RESCHED flag for each CPU rather than for each thread?

Tags: linux-kernel

In linux kernel 2.6.11, the TIF_NEED_RESCHED flag is recorded in thread_info struct for each task.

I searched the kernel and found that, it can only be set by the current thread on the CPU for itself. So why not put the TIF_NEED_RESCHED in some per CPU structure instead of in each thread_info?

If this flag is only used to show **that current thread on this cpu** needs schedule(), then I think perhaps it is OK to record it for each CPU rather than for each thread?

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

I didn't write it, so I don't know if what I think is the reason, or not.

`thread_info` is very easy to access in the kernel. In this context, it's equivalent to per-CPU data.
It's used to indicate that a reschedule is needed, and only remains between the timer interrupt and the actual reschedule. So obviously, the running process can't change in between, and setting data on `thread_info` is equivalent to setting per-cpu.

If you're worried about memory consumption, then one bit per process is a very small worry. And considering that the flags take 32 bits with or without it, it's even smaller.